# Merging multiple SpatRasters by sum in R package Terra

Tags: r, merge, spatial, r-raster, terra

I have two SpatRasters that I want to merge. When they merge I want each pixel to sum the values from both rasters. I have tried the following code but it does not work. How can I do this?

```
abd_projected <- project(abd_Americas, crs, method = "near")
abd2_projected <- project(abd2_Americas, crs, method = "near")

class(abd_projected)
[1] "SpatRaster"
attr(,"package")
[1] "terra"
class(abd2_projected)
[1] "SpatRaster"
attr(,"package")
[1] "terra"

merged_abd <- merge(abd_projected, abd2_projected fun = sum )

Error: unexpected symbol in "merged_abd <- merge(abd_projected, 
abd2_projected fun"

merged_abd <- merge(abd_projected, abd2_projected, FUN = sum )
Error: [sprc] list elements should be 'SpatRaster'
is of class: function
```

I have also tried

```
mergedABD <- raster::merge(abd_projected, abd2_projected, 
tolerance=0.1)
```

and

```
abdall_projected<- c(abd_projected, abd2_projected)
rsum <- app(abdall_projected, sum)
```

neither worked

If it helps the data I am trying to merge to plot is species data from the package ebirdst. I want to combine two species abundance spatial (raster) datasets before I plot them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mosaic` instead, so you can indicate `"sum"` as the function used to calculate the pixel values in the overlapping pixels.

```
library(terra)
    
resul <- mosaic(abd_projected, abd2_projected, fun = "sum")
```